# Communication Of iPhone and Google App Engine

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine

How can I get a pdf data (stored in datastore as blob) from iphone if i make a request to google app engine?

When I use 
        self.response.out.write('asadasd');
in google app engine code
I can see this 'asadasd' in iPhone.

But i don't know how to set this communication so that i can get a pdf data from i phone.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand corretly, you want to send an pdf file to a webapplication, right?
I think it would be a solution to base64 code the binary data of the pdf on the iphone (that comes from your blob) and then send it via http post to the webapplication.

Comment: No, actually, I have something stored in web application's datastore as blob. I create a http post request from iPhone everything is perfect. But i dont know how to return pdf data to iphone.

Comment: ah ok. sorry. My guess would be quite similar though: get the  blob out of the database, do a base64 encode on that and write the resulting string to the response . on the iphone side, base64 decode what you get - and you should have your pdf.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the proper headers before writing to the output stream:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=filename.pdf'
self.response.out.write(...)
```